# before_filter running multiple time and growing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this funny situation whereby I see my before_filter executing multiple times for one access.

My filter is called auth_user_filter and it logs using logger.info("Yada Yada Yada"). It gets set globally to run before all actions. When I access an action over my browser it prints the following (depending on what call it is)

The first call prints

```
 Yada Yada Yada
```

The second call prints

```
 Yada Yada Yada
 Yada Yada Yada
```

The third call prints

```
 Yada Yada Yada
 Yada Yada Yada
 Yada Yada Yada
```

And so on.

This only happens in development mode and I was wondering if anybody knows why?

Comment: Have you played with the logger or something?

Comment: Ya I had wondered if it was the logger not getting cleared before it writes out or something. But I have not played with it.

Answer (score 2):

How exactly are you setting it globally? Sounds like the `before_filter :foo` is being called on something that is not reloaded (possibly `ActionController::Base`) from a file that is being reloaded (like a controller file).

If this is so, move the before filter to the `ApplicationController`, or move the `before_filter` call to an initializer.

Comment: I have the before_filter code in UserManagementApplicationConreoller. And I have ApplicationController < UserManagementApplicationController < ActionController::Base

I do this because UserManagement is a Rails Engine plugin I use in many of my apps. So defining the code in there makes it a lot more DRY. Then any apps that use this plugin I just have ApplicationController inherit UserManagementApplicationController versus ActionController::Base.

I am not sure if your suggestion explains why it only happens in Development mode though and not in Production. Thanks for input.